# Google Maps Bounds inaccurate

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

my problem is related to the way how LatLngBounds.extend() method works. I am not sure if this is a bug or not but it does not work as intended. I expect bounds to contain all points included in it. Unfortunately it works really strangely in my case. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy5dC/4/.

```
var locationBBOX = [
'(42.00, -142.00) (70.00, -50.00)', //CANADA
'(47.274719, 5.864166000000068) (55.053055, 15.038886999999932)',//GERMANY
//'(40.00, 27.00) (70.00, 179.00)'//RUSSIA
];
```

In lines 23-27 you will find definitions of bounding boxes for 3 countries. Currently Russia is commented out and everything works like a charm. The problem begins when Russia is included in bounds - the map does not show the correct bounding box. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: It's to do with west Canada and east Russia being more than 180 degrees apart in longitude. Bring Russia's NE Lng down to 38.00 deg and everything is fine. Back up to 39.00 deg and the issue re-emerges. I don't know of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`boundingBoxPoints` does not encompass the same area as `bbox` does.

You may create the correct box for the bounds by using a Rectangle with the bounds-property set to bbox, and when you create Markers for all the points you will see that they are all located within this box.

Demo(the blue rectangle marks the real bounds): [**http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/EGDFH/show/**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/EGDFH/show/)

But I'm afraid that's not the desired result, unfortunately I have no solution at this time, also `union()` will not help here(it seems to be just a wrapper for `extend(sw)` & `extend(ne)` ).

Comment: yes, I see your point. Great presentation, thanks! I think  I need to find some other solution myself:(