# Google Maps JS API Fit Bounds Not Working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm having a very strange problem with my Google Maps implementation.  I am getting back an array from a REST service that gives me lat/lng and I am in turn using that information to put markers on the map and implement functionality.

That part works fine, it's when it comes to taking the markers output on the page and getting their bounds and zooming the map to them that I get to the problem.  I have read several solutions and I have attempted implementing them to the best of my ability.

Here's my implementation:

```
// Reset the maps bounds
MapView.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);

// Get the new map bounds
for (var i=0, j=MapView.markers.length; i<j; i++){
    var marker = MapView.markers[i],
        lat = marker.position.lat(),
        lng = marker.position.lng(),
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    MapView.bounds.extend(latlng);
};

// Set the map bounds to the new bounds
MapView.map.fitBounds(MapView.bounds);
```

Here is a list of the coordinates being used:

```
21.245445,-105.167631
41.887668,-87.622522
49.817492,15.472962
50.075538,14.4378
33.951611,-118.387578
41.887668,-87.622522
14.782827,-90.793702
33.741973,-78.817013
45.922225,-95.408973
28.320306,-81.422964
36.166667,-86.783333
-17.82922,31.053961
-8.708704,115.169616
41.901514,12.460774
-34.013717,23.054811
20.483443,-86.971039
34.933333,34.083333
6.428055,-9.429499
38.79142,-95.960607
43.771033,11.248001
46.271588,13.95641
33.773,-78.779504
40.789342,-3.249749
20.926822,-156.695125
46.271588,13.95641
18.853921,-71.300939
36.462205,-5.011611
25.788969,-80.226439
50.36809,8.73632
37.540667,126.948346
45.495992,-121.5879
14.782827,-90.793701
0,0
13,-76
20.431006,-86.908065
40.75694,-73.984872
64.143935,-21.934099
-17.816667,25.15
12.879721,121.774017
32.640054,-117.084196
-16.522046,28.850942
40.280559,22.50584
39.202686,-106.831683
36.122611,-115.170973
38.79142,-95.960607
18.126285,-65.440099
22.876396,-109.918562
30.36884,-86.324846
36.076518,-115.153343
36.0443,14.251222
41.894809,-87.624214
36.0443,14.251222
-34.035086,23.046469
36.42,25.431667
-17.82922,31.053961
20.696686,-105.292631
18.533333,-68.366667
42.407211,-71.382437
21.158964,-86.845937
9.748917,-83.753428
14.782827,-90.793701
34.852965,32.361479
34.939737,32.461585
34.052234,-118.243685
64.143935,-21.934099
35.369598,24.482727
52.407927,3.222711
47.497912,19.040235
21.158964,-86.845937
37.446719,25.328862
21.160386,-86.843338
39.770247,21.182861
36.124253,-115.168476
46.421684,15.856075
116.468401,39.947856
41.553221,-70.608589
43.706449,7.292265
39.415044,21.737618
21.158964,-86.845937
20.629559,-87.126904
36.832012,25.897065
50.075538,14.4378
8.87509,98.352656
57.702051,11.982304
-24.183889,29.012778
38.904253,-77.047904
0,0
-25.360413,27.09947
55.940209,-3.225319
36.286023,-5.27918
-3.386069,39.971999
20.749045,-105.31098
17.280151,-62.689038
21.040195,-104.358146
14.782827,-90.793702
20.696686,-105.292631
50.071287,14.397221
51.891877,-8.493827
```

Then I used those bounds to create a poly line to try and find out where the problem was, and the wierd part is even that is wrong, but the map isn't even zooming/panning to THOSE bounds.

Code for poly line:

```
var ne = MapView.bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = MapView.bounds.getSouthWest();

var boundingBoxPoints = [
    ne, new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng()),
    sw, new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng()), ne
];

var boundingBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: boundingBoxPoints,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
 });

boundingBox.setMap(MapView.map);
```

And a picture of the result (this is as the map loads, un-altered):

[image: Bounding Box Vs Map Zoom/Position]

It will either load like that (if I'm lucky) or load with most of the trips out of the top of the map with only a couple showing and most of the map canvas gray.

I am a total loss right now, could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have a link to a map that exhibits the problem or a jsfiddle that does, so we can see the code in action?  The behavior looks like you are extending the bounds with some invalid points.  The polygon is drawing incorrectly because it is going the short way around the world.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see much more of the code since the company I'm at would throw a fit.  I can tell you I am checking if the lat and lng are valid by only adding a point if they are within the valid range of values by wrapping the valid bits of code in an if statement: `if (lat >= (-75) && lat <= 75 && lng >= (-180) && lng <= 180)`

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a set of points (the don't need to be real) that causes this to happen with the code you have posted?  I use fitBounds all the time, the only time I see problems is when there is bad data.  Is `MapView.markers[i].position` a google.maps.LatLng object?  If so you can simplify your code to: `MapView.bounds.extend(MapView.markers[i].position);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Bounds inaccurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569800/google-maps-bounds-inaccurate)

Comment: List of coordinates added as requested.